# Assignning dates according to categorical variable

Tags: r

I have a set of `Payment Date` in the following form:

```
ID  Payment Date   
1   18-01-01
1   18-02-03
2   18-04-03
2   18-05-08
2   18-06-06
3   17-12-23
3   18-01-22
3   18-02-24
4   17-11-09
4   18-12-06
```

I would like to add a column, `Activation Date`, as the earliest payment date for each `ID`, like:

```
ID  Payment Date   Activation Date
1   18-01-01       18-01-01
1   18-02-03       18-01-01
2   18-04-03       18-04-03
2   18-05-08       18-04-03
2   18-06-06       18-04-03
3   17-12-23       17-12-23
3   18-01-22       17-12-23
3   18-02-24       17-12-23
4   17-11-09       17-11-09
4   18-12-06       17-11-09
```

I am wondering instead of going into a loop and take care of each ID one by one, there must be a much more clever way to do this.

Comment: How do you generate the Activation Date values?

Comment: `ave(as.Date(df$PaymentDate, "%y-%m-%d"), df$ID, FUN = min)`

Comment: @RonakShah should be the top answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
ID  PaymentDate   
1   18-01-01
1   18-02-03
2   18-04-03
2   18-05-08
2   18-06-06
3   17-12-23
3   18-01-22
3   18-02-24
4   17-11-09
4   18-12-06
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivationDate = min(ymd(PaymentDate))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#     ID PaymentDate ActivationDate
#   <int> <fct>       <date>        
# 1     1 18-01-01    2018-01-01    
# 2     1 18-02-03    2018-01-01    
# 3     2 18-04-03    2018-04-03    
# 4     2 18-05-08    2018-04-03    
# 5     2 18-06-06    2018-04-03    
# 6     3 17-12-23    2017-12-23    
# 7     3 18-01-22    2017-12-23    
# 8     3 18-02-24    2017-12-23    
# 9     4 17-11-09    2017-11-09    
#10     4 18-12-06    2017-11-09
```

Assuming that your dataset is already ordered and you don't want to use `Date` formats, you can use

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ActivationDate = first(PaymentDate)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `data.table`

data:

```
df1<-
        fread("ID  Payment
    1   18-01-01
    1   18-02-03
    2   18-04-03
    2   18-05-08
    2   18-06-06
    3   17-12-23
    3   18-01-22
    3   18-02-24
    4   17-11-09
    4   18-12-06") %>% setDF
```

code:

```
data.table::setDT(df1)[,Activation := Payment[1],by="ID"][]
```

result:

```
 #   ID  Payment Activation
 #1:  1 18-01-01   18-01-01
 #2:  1 18-02-03   18-01-01
 #3:  2 18-04-03   18-04-03
 #4:  2 18-05-08   18-04-03
 #5:  2 18-06-06   18-04-03
 #6:  3 17-12-23   17-12-23
 #7:  3 18-01-22   17-12-23
 #8:  3 18-02-24   17-12-23
 #9:  4 17-11-09   17-11-09
#10:  4 18-12-06   17-11-09
```

---

quick tipp:

- Never use "spaces" in column names again
- use underscore or camelcase. eg: `payment_date`, `paymentDate`

Comment: Thanks Andre, this is my first post so I was a bit puzzled how to post stuff. I understand this in R :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

Your dataset:

```
df=read.table(text="ID  PaymentDate   
          1   18-01-01
          1   18-02-03
          2   18-04-03
          2   18-05-08
          2   18-06-06
          3   17-12-23
          3   18-01-22
          3   18-02-24
          4   17-11-09
          4   18-12-06",header=T)
```

Code

```
# we can first find the minimum PaymentDate using the inner query and then
# populate the data.frame using the inner query
sqldf("select a.ID,a.PaymentDate, b.ActivationDate from df as a JOIN 
 (select ID,min(PaymentDate) as ActivationDate from df group by ID) as b where a.ID=b.ID")
```

Output:

```
   ID PaymentDate ActivationDate
1   1    18-01-01       18-01-01
2   1    18-02-03       18-01-01
3   2    18-04-03       18-04-03
4   2    18-05-08       18-04-03
5   2    18-06-06       18-04-03
6   3    17-12-23       17-12-23
7   3    18-01-22       17-12-23
8   3    18-02-24       17-12-23
9   4    17-11-09       17-11-09
10  4    18-12-06       17-11-09
```